# Java how to get first N lines of exception including the type of exception?

Tags: java, exception

Let's say I have this exception showing in the console:

```
java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: /path/here/directory
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile.move(UnixCopyFile.java:466)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.move(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:267)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1421)
    at class.method(class.java:158)
    at class.method(class.java:234)
    at class.method(class.java:23)
...
...
... more lines ...
```

How could I extract the first N lines INCLUDING `java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: /path/here/directory`?

I have written this to get the first 2 lines:

```
String stackTrace = "";
if (error != null ) {
    StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = error.getStackTrace();
    stackTrace = stackTraceElements[0].toString() + stackTraceElements[1].toString();
}
```

But this only yielded:

```
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile.move(UnixCopyFile.java:466)at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.move(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:267)
```

I was under the impression that `StackTraceElements[0]` would be the `java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: /path/here/directory` but it wasn't and i have no idea how to get the proper amount of N lines to include this.

Comment: if you debug you will see `java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException` is the cause, so if you want that part as well `error.toString()` will give you the exception

Comment: @ManeeshaIndrachapa what about the ```/path/here/directory``` portion?

Comment: Print the error itself.

Answer (score 1):

Print the Exception also:

```
public class Tracer
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Tracer app = new Tracer ();
        app.execute ();
    }

    private void execute ()
    {
        try
        {
            failure (5);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = e.getStackTrace ();
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder ();
            builder.append (e);
            builder.append ("\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                builder.append (stackTraceElements[i].toString ());
                builder.append ("\n");
            }
            System.out.println (builder);
        }
    }

    private void failure (int n) throws Exception
    {
        if (n <= 0)
        {
            throw new Exception ("Exception message");
        }
        else
        {
            failure (n - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I foresee a problem in the case where there are fewer than 3 elements in the stack trace.

Comment: Change the loop to end when i < 3 || i >= stackTraceElements.length

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to concatenate the error message with the toString of each stack trace entry. Use `Arrays.stream()` with `limit(N)` to get you the required number of entries in the stack trace, convert them to String and join with line separator.

Try a variation of this:

```
Exception ex = new Exception("File not found message");
int depth = 3;
String stackN = Arrays.stream(ex.getStackTrace()).limit(depth)
                  .map(String::valueOf)
                // .map(s -> "   at "+s)
                  .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
String all    = ex.toString()+System.lineSeparator() + stackN;
System.out.println(all);
```

You may want to experiment with different formatting or indentation (tabs / space prefix etc) which could be achieved with extra map step inserted into the stream, such as `.map(s -> "    "+s)`